# Insert/Update a Column of Null Values with a Column From a View or Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having difficulty updating a column in a table which contains `NULLS` after a previous `INSERT`. The easiest way to illustrate my predicament is with an example:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(p_ID INT, T varchar(50))

INSERT INTO TEST(p_ID)
SELECT *
FROM vw_MyView -- Contains a column of ints, but I will use strings here
```

The output as expected

```
SELECT * FROM TEST

p_ID    T
6       NULL
7       NULL
8       NULL
9       NULL
10      NULL
11      NULL
12      NULL
13      NULL
14      NULL
```

My first attempt to add data was to insert the values from the view into (T)

```
INSERT INTO TEST(T)
SELECT *
FROM vw_MyView
WHERE T IS NULL -- Wrong! "Invalid column name 'T'."
```

But of course, the WHERE clause goes with the view... Thanks, Google.

My second attempt was to use `UPDATE`

```
BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE TEST
    SET TEST.T = T.ID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM vw_MyView
    ) T
    WHERE TEST.T IS NULL -- Why is this allowed here?

    SELECT * FROM TEST

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Which also fails because it only uses the first row of the view to update the column

```
p_ID    T
6       a
7       a
8       a
9       a
10      a
11      a
12      a
13      a
14      a
```

The desired output is

```
p_ID    T
6       a
7       b
8       c
9       d
10      e
11      f
12      g
13      h
14      i
```

Please note the (p_ID) column does not exist in the actual table, I only used it for a quick and dirty example. Besides the obvious question of how to
update/insert the desired values to the column, I feel that I've my have a flaw in my conception of when and how to use `UPDATE` or `INSERT` and `WHERE`. Any help would be great. Thanks.

***UPDATE***

I've updated my example to clear up some confusion as to the `p_ID` column, it doesn't exist in the table, I wish it did... **My main goal is to get the values from the view to update the `NULL` values in the column (T)**. Thanks.

Comment: Do not use `SELECT *` instead use column names as `INSERT INTO Test(T) SELECT T FROM YourView;` I suppose you're looking for an `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for

```
INSERT INTO Test(p_ID, T)
SELECT IntCol, IntCol
FROM vw_MyView;
```

And according to the desired output, if you're going to `UPDATE` the table then

```
UPDATE Test
SET T = p_Id;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ecba91c42ce1815a574f5dd4ee986d66)**

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You seem to want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (p_id, T)
    SELECT v.?, v.?    -- ? is the column name for the view
    FROM vw_MyView v;
```

Or, if you already have the data in the table, you don't need the view at all:

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.T = t.ID
FROM TEST t 
WHERE t.T IS NULL ;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not trying to the (T) column with the value of (p_ID) but with a separate column from another object... I've seemed to have caused some confusion, I will correct my example.

Answer (score 0):

Update `test` with data from `vw_MyView`

```
update t
set T = v.charCol
from test t
join vw_MyView v on t.p_ID = v.IntCol;
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is to use *.
Try to always accurately list the required fields. That is, in your case, you need to rewrite it as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (p_ID INT, T varchar (50));

INSERT INTO TEST (p_ID)
SELECT p_ID
FROM vw_MyView;
```

Similarly, in defining views, avoid using *, always list required fields explicitly
Update:

```
START TRANS
UPDATE t
SET t.T=mv.ID
FROM TEST as t
INNER JOIN vw_MyView as mv on t.Key=mv.Key
and t.T IS NULL;
ROLLBACK TRAN
```